# Alter MySQL's SHOW COLUMS "Extra" value

Tags: mysql, alter-table, alter

Is there a way to change te value of the `Extra` column that is shown with the `SHOW COLUMNS`/`DESCRIBE` sentences?

The documentation about this column states the following:

> **Extra**
>
> Any additional information that is available about a given column. The
>   value is nonempty in these cases:
>
> - auto_increment for columns that have the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.
> - on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP or DATETIME columns that
>     have the ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attribute.
> - VIRTUAL GENERATED or VIRTUAL STORED for generated columns.
> - DEFAULT_GENERATED for columns that have an expression default value.

I have the next table columns information but I wish to remove the `Extra` value of the `start_date` column.

Is there a way to do this?

```
+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
|       Field        |        Type        | Null | Key |      Default      |       Extra       |
+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id_machine_product | "int(10) unsigned" | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| ...                | ...                | ...  | ... | ...               | ...               |
| start_date         | timestamp          | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+--------------------+--------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

I have implemented a fingerprint validation method in PHP that diffs the DESCRIBE tables values, I have database versions in production that doesn't have that Extra value even though those columns have an expression default value, so currently, I wish to alter that value so I don't get errors from my implemented fingerprint validation method in my development environment.

The production databases are in Mysql < 8.0 so, as per Bill Karwin's answer, I'm having trouble with my MySQL development environment version that is 8.0

Comment: *"Is there a way to change te value of the Extra column that is shown with the SHOW COLUMNS/DESCRIBE sentences?"* Why would you want to change this output.. The simple answer is you can't unless you `ALTER` the table and remove those options.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have implemented a fingerprint validation method in PHP that diffs the `DESCRIBE` tables values, I have database versions in production that doesn't have that `Extra` value even though those columns have an expression default value, so currently, I wish to alter that value so I don't get errors from my implemented fingerprint validation method in my development environment.

Comment: Ok now i see i've also posted a answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Topicstarters comment**

> I have implemented a fingerprint validation method in PHP that diffs
>   the DESCRIBE tables values, I have database versions in production
>   that doesn't have that Extra value even though those columns have an
>   expression default value, so currently, I wish to alter that value so
>   I don't get errors from my implemented fingerprint validation method
>   in my development environment.

The more standard SQL method would be which also works in MySQL 8

**Query**

```
SELECT 
    information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME AS 'Field'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_TYPE AS 'Type'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.IS_NULLABLE AS 'Null'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_KEY AS 'Key'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT AS 'Default'
    , information_schema.COLUMNS.EXTRA AS 'Extra'
FROM 
    information_schema.TABLES
INNER JOIN
    information_schema.COLUMNS ON information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME =  information_schema.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
WHERE
    information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_NAME = '<table>'
```

This query should match the output of `DESCRIBE`
Then you could use `REPLACE()` on `information_schema.COLUMNS.EXTRA` output to remove or edit the way you want. 
 For example removing extra features like `DEFAULT_GENERATED` or `VIRTUAL GENERATED` ([generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html))

Comment: This sounds like a very promising workaround, but I'm having an issue with your query, I'm getting 4 times the rows from `SHOW COLUMS`/`DESCRIBE`, am I missing something?

Comment: *"I'm getting 4 times the rows from"* it should not be possible so i have no idea what you are doing @Rodrirokr the query it is somehow tested with https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h8NTqdT6Sa52w69Uu8WTpu/0 as i used it before to answer a question in the past.

Comment: Silly me! This query searchs in the entire server, I have multiple databases with the same table names (one for each client).

Comment: *"i have multiple databases with the same table names"* Yes the query should ideally implement a `information_schema.TABLES.TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() ` filter @Rodrirokr assuming you working with `USE database` or a default database when connecting with PHP

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question *why* you want to eliminate the Extra information. It's just noting that the column's default is an expression.

To make the Extra field blank, you must make the column's default either a constant value or NULL.

```
mysql> create table foo ( id int unsigned primary key, start_date timestamp not null default current_timestamp);

mysql> show columns from foo;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                   |
| start_date | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+

mysql> alter table foo modify start_date timestamp default null;

mysql> show columns from foo;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| start_date | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Note that the Extra information "DEFAULT_GENERATED" is only present in MySQL 8.0. I suspect it's related to the new feature to support expressions in the DEFAULT clause. Any other expression also results in this Extra information.

```
mysql > alter table foo modify start_date timestamp default (now() + interval 1 hour);

mysql> show columns from foo;
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default                   | Extra             |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                      |                   |
| start_date | timestamp        | YES  |     | (now() + interval 1 hour) | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Wait does MySQL 8.0 besides CHECK contraints, expressions in indexes now also support expressions in default?

Comment: Marked as the answer for the MySQL 8.0 part.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, yes, this is a new feature in MySQL 8.0. You can use an expression as a default if you put it in parentheses. See `[DEFAULT {literal | (expr)} ]` in the syntax reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin i never noticed it before when i looked what was changed in MySQL 8 syntax..

Comment: See also "Data type support" in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-nutshell.html

Answer (score 0):

you need an alter table statement. Something like

```
ALTER TABLE `document` MODIFY COLUMN `start_date ` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

You can set a default value like

```
DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL
```

Comment: Indeed. That would generate a value "auto_increment" in the extra column as stated in the quoted documentation, nonetheless the question is about if there's a way to alter only the extra value, indepently of the auto-generated value of setting a column with `AUTO_INCREMENT` like in your answer's example.

Comment: Yes, you need to set the default value to something.